# Cannot find SpecFlow Feature Files option in Add New Item window - VS2022

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium-webdriver, specflow

I am new to visual studio and specflow. I have visual studio 20２２　community edition in my windows 10 and I have followed all steps and installed specflow extention in visual studio. But I cannot add a feature file from right click on project> Add new. I cannot see specflow and I only see WPF application. Why??

[image]

I tried to create a new file without template but couldn't do it. I want to see specflow templates when I create new project.

Comment: Are you able to add a test project (literally a project meant to contain unit tests)? I don't think there is a "specflow" project. You need to add a unit test project. The SpecFlow extension for Visual Studio allows you to write feature files, and provides support of intellisense. Under the hood, SpecFlow tests are just plain old unit tests. The feature files are parsed and converted to unit tests that should show up in Test Explorer in Visual Studio.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. No, I don't see any template includes "Test". I see, "WPF Application" , "WPF Class Library", "WPF Custom Control Library".... ??

Comment: I feel like you are missing some workloads in Visual Studio. You should have project templates to Test projects.

Comment: Maybe try repairing the Visual Studio installation?

Comment: Can you choose "Tests" or "Test Projects" in the "All project types" dropdown menu towards the upper-right?

Comment: Yes, Ive already done it but appeared nothing. I don't know why I cannot have the test template. I've also installed Package NUnit, xunit, MSTest with NuGet Package Manager Console. Maybe it doesn't show test template because in community edition? Do you think I can have specflow test project without template?

Comment: VS Community should have test projects available. I really think you are missing some workloads in Visual Studio. Have you tried repairing the Visual Studio installation yet?

Comment: After installing SpecFlow for Visual Studio 2022, you need to reopen Visual Studio (you must close everything and reopen it). If it still doesn't work, you can try to use Visual Studio Installer to repair Visual Studio and reinstall SpecFlow for Visual Studio 2022.

Comment: I've already done all. I guess it's problem of edition. I'll give up this version and will see if I can use enterprise version when I'm going to start to work in company anyway. Thank you.

Comment: I finally found by myself that it was because of the problem of edition. If it's VS 2022 Community Edition, I couldn't find any template of specflow even after installing extention specflow. But when I installed VS 2022 Enterprise Edition, I found specflow template after installed extention without any problem.

Comment: The Community Edition should have this option too. I have VS 2022 Community at home, and I'm able to create SpecFlow feature files just like I can in Enterprise edition. I really think you have a problem with your installation for Community Edition.